# JS preloader leaking certain content before the page is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Hello StackOverflow people,

I've been trying implement a JS preloader from a template, unfortunately, I can't make it work so that it doesn't leak some content before the page is loaded...

This is the JS function =>

```
    var clPreloader = function() {
        
        $("html").addClass('cl-preload');

        $WIN.on('load', function() {

            //force page scroll position to top at page refresh
            $("html").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'normal');

            // will first fade out the loading animation 
            $("#loader").fadeOut("slow", function() {
                // will fade out the whole DIV that covers the website.
                $("#preloader").delay(300).fadeOut("slow");
            }); 
            
            // for hero content animations 
            $("html").removeClass('cl-preload');
            $("html").addClass('cl-loaded');
        });
    };

[...]

(function ssInit() {
        
        clPreloader();

    })();
 
[...]
        
})(jQuery);
```

(Note that the $WIN varriable is defined by above) =>

```
    $WIN = $(window);

    // Add the User Agent to the <html>
    // will be used for IE10 detection (Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; Trident/6.0))
    var doc = document.documentElement;
    doc.setAttribute('data-useragent', navigator.userAgent);
```

Here's the CSS that the JS script Add/Remove =>

```
html.cl-preload .home-content__main {
    opacity: 0;
    display: none !important;
}

html.cl-loaded .home-content__main {
    animation-duration: 2s;
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeIn;
    animation-name: fadeIn;
}

html.no-csstransitions .home-content__main {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

It seems pretty smart to me but no matter what I try, it's leaking some text elements from .home-content__main class before the page is loaded. You can see it an action here =>

https://dev-preview.voresak.cc/
(Sorry about the missing SSL certificate...)

[I should also add that the theme demo works perfectly fine in this respect..](https://preview.colorlib.com/#glint).

**What I have already tried**

– messing around with hiding the elements in .home-content__main class with CSS (visibility: hidden !important; display: none !important; and alike)... no success.

–  Swaping the $WIN.on('load', function() with $(window).on('load', function() & $('document').ready(function() ... no success.

– For a long while I thought the script is messed up by the [Rocket Loader](https://developers.cloudflare.com/fundamentals/speed/rocket-loader/) but even when I whitlisted this script with all the dependencies, it still behave the same...

Pretty much run out the ideas... What am I missing?

Thanks for any suggestions and opinions!

P.

Comment: You are embedding your scripts at the end of body, so the browser has everything that comes before at least parsed already at this point, and is likely to have started rendering already at this point as well. And it has to wait until the jQuery library has finished loading as well ... Set the class name on the HTML element without jQuery, and outside of your function that needs to wait until jQuery is loaded.

Comment: Oh wow! You are amazing and fast. Indeed, hardwiring the "cl-preload" class to the HTML tag did the trick. Thanks so much!

Comment: I rather meant that you still set it via JavaScript ... otherwise, users with disabled JavaScript would be left with a completely empty page then. (Not sure how much of the rest of the site will work then though, so that might not be your primary focus, don't know.)

Comment: I see... I may actually try that. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

To make sure that it is not the order of loading the scripts for the FOUC (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content), assign a style attribute to the element and remove it with javascript.

```js
window.onload = (event) => {

  setTimeout(function() { 
    $(".loading").remove()
    $(".hidden-while-loading").removeAttr("style")
  }, 2000)

}
```

```css
.loading {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
.loading:after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  width: 34px;
  height: 34px;
  margin: 8px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 6px solid #222;
  border-color: #222 transparent #222 transparent;
  animation: loadingAni 1.2s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes loadingAni {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="loading"></div>

<div class="hidden-while-loading" style="display:none">hidden-while-loading</div>
```

Comment: I wanted to suggest something similar, it would be definitively best to assign something in the CSS like display:none; and remove this with JS